# getting Netezza Error when adding an analytic function

Tags: sql, analytics, netezza

I'm adding an Analytic function to a query that works otherwise and I'm getting an error.

Here's the top line. It's just two values, One being an analytic function that uses sum():

> select i.CPC_CD, sum(MTD_AVG_BAL_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY MBA_ACCT_NBR,
>   CPC_CD ) AS       "Total Balance 2"  from (

when I try to add a "group by i.CPC_CD" at the bottom I get the following error:

> ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  relation does not exist
>   IDP_PRD_US_MARKETING.ADMIN.CONS_ACT

ADMIN.CONS_ACT is one of the tables I use in the inner query. The whole query is too large to list.I think I'm just asking for why adding "group by" would cause this type of problem. Also THe error says "IDP_PRD_INTERFACE.ADMIN.CONS_ACT" With ADMIN as the Schema when the actual schema and table name should be "IDP_PRD_INTERFACE.USCA.V_CONS_ACCT_F" could that mean anything?

Comment: If you are using `group by`, why are you using an analytic function?  Although they can be used together, it does not seem necessary in this case.

Comment: Because the CPC_CD is not an aggregate function and sum(MTD_AVG_BAL_AMT) is.  Also in the actual query I have other Aggregate functions as well like count(), sum() that are not analytic.